# How to let loop only stop when statement is true

Tags: linux, bash, loops

i wish to run a bash script, that will only stop when the statement is true.

My bash script code is below. I am comparing a date, if compare date is false, script should not stop, keep running till it reach the correct time.

I'm meeting a problem, i wish the script is like this  " current time is 03180932015 , if the time reach 031809402015, it will echo to a file, and stop."
But now it's not. If the statement is false it will end the script.

```
time=`date '+%m%d%H%M%Y'`
if [ $time == "031809402015" ]; then
  #echo "hellodd:" > ./aaa.txt
  ipmitool -I lanplus -H 192.168.2.2 -U USERID -P PASSW0RD sel list > xxx.txt
fi
done
```

Comment: Have you try until loop??

Comment: Do you want the script to do something until that time, or do *nothing* until that time?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: Also take a look at the `at` command, which runs a specified command or script at a specified time.

Comment: Beta: i wants to do nothing until that time

Comment: How to close this question, i had solve this question. I'm unable to post question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
until [[ "$(date '+%m%d%H%M%Y')"  == "031809402015" ]]; do
  sleep 1
done
ipmitool ...
```

Comment: I went and try, I wish when the time occur,  do the command below ipmi ..... For example the current time is 031809402015, if the time reach 031809452015, then execute the command, Is there any method.

Comment: Could anyone help me, i'm unable to post question. Please me please

Answer (score 1):

Try  this:

The while loop is perfect for a situation where you need to execute a set of commands while some condition is true. Sometimes you need to execute a set of commands until a condition is true.

```
until command 
do 
Statement(s) to be executed until command is true 
 done
```

Here Shell command is evaluated. If the resulting value is false, given statement(s) are executed. If command istrue then no statement would be not executed and program would jump to the next line after done statement.